# Using Ajax to add an item to array in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have an mcv project in which i use a class to use multiple classes in a view it looks like this

```
  public class Birlesik
    {
        public User Theuser{ get; set; }
        public Lang_User[] Thelanguser { get; set; }
        public  PT_User[] Theptuser { get; set; }
}
```

I need to create a 3 forms in the view with different button clicks. 2 of these forms should return a model on button click which then i have to add to the arraylists in the class without refreshing the page. So i wonder if there is a way to do this with ajax.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: i can give an idea for this ..take 3 partial views for each of the form(3) and these 3 partial views will render in one main view..you will submit the first form(Theuser) using mvc ajax begin form.. in the controller do your stuff and return the second partial view..same way to third form.. at the end you will have 3 forms data to store..

Comment: ty i will try this